# DatePicker creation exception on Galaxy Mini 2.2

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-datepicker

This problem is driving me crazy.  It only appears to happen on the Galaxy Mini, a phone to which I have no access to.

The exception is the following:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at android.widget.NumberPicker.twSetMaxInputLength(NumberPicker.java:302)
    at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:128)
    at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:113)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
```

The error happens on a TouchWiz specific method which doesn't exist on stock Android.

How can I debug this problem?  I can't seem to find emulator images or sources to TouchWiz, though one would expect sources to be out there somewhere.

Does anybody have any pointers?